# Azure Mobile app - QuickStart trouble

Tags: azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I've downloaded Xamarin.Forms QuickStart Projects(server and cliente) from azure mobile app, then have published server project, so far so good, but i cannot access table controllers, unless i add query string as described.

http://myservice.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0

or if i add ms_skipversioncheck to true in the portal.

Probably something related with server or client versions discrepance.

Even if i update all nuget packages, same thing, just receive BadRequest (400)

But with this server described above, when i run client Project(android simulator in visual studio) it Works fine in not syncing mode.

Once i download nuget sqlite localstore and uncomment the line:

//#define OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED

and make this line :
 await RefreshItems(true, syncItems: true);

to enable off-line mode, i receive only BadRequest(400), again

I dont know what i should check to make the versions compatible.

I did not include stack trace or logs because BadRequest is the only thing i received.

Let me known if you need some further information.

Thanks

Edit:
I check this link out, but i coudnt solve my issue.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning.md

Its drive me crazy

Answer (score 3):

In the body of the 400 bad request response, there is usually an error message included. 
You can view this with Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or another web debugger.

Example:

Request
GET http://azielnettest.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem

Response
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"message":"No API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of '2.0.0'.  For more information and supported clients see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=690568#2.0.0"}

Request
http://azielnettest.azurewebsites.net/tables/todoitem?zumo-api-version=2.0.0

Response
200 
{data....}

That's step 1 on debugging.

Step 2 would be to check

a) The packages.config of your server project that you deployed to your site.
You should find something like this...

```
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server" version="1.0.119.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

b) The packages.config of your Xamarin Forms project.

```
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="win81" />
```

If your Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client version is lower than 2.0.0, it will not work against the Azure Mobile App backend because the zumo-api-version is not included in the headers in older clients.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Aziel, the versions of quickstart Project match the versions you mentioned, and the Project runs ok without off line mode enabled, once i add WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore nuget package(no code changes), the Project does not work anymore and start to receive bad requests.

Comment: @gilberto, have you tried running Fiddler to see what the requests look like as they go out to your service?  Or, you can add a logging handler (see [sample LoggingHandler here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files/blob/master/src/client/MobileAppsFilesSample/Helpers/LoggingHandler.cs#L63)) to your client and check the debug output. If it's behaving differently in offline mode, that means that the requests are somehow different.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the intructions on top off TodoItemManager.cs file.

// To add offline sync support: add the NuGet package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore
// to all projects in the solution and uncomment the symbol definition OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED
// For Xamarin.iOS, also edit AppDelegate.cs and uncomment the call to SQLitePCL.CurrentPlatform.Init()
// For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620342

The correct nuget package is Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore, off-line mode is working now.

Att

Comment: Talk too soon, the initial refresh Works with off-line mode enabled , but after insert off line(Works well), but it not Works when pushing the insert. Follow the exception in cliente when try to push data: {"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"item.__version":["An error has occurred."]}} and this is server streaming log : Error       Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync, Exception=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not find member '__version' on object of type 'TodoItem'. Path '__version', line 1, position 87.
   Stucked again.