# Xamarin.ios Azure toDo QuickStart Update the client app to support offline features

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios

I am working through the Xamarin.ios Azure toDo QuickStart, when i get to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-offline-data

Update the client app to support offline features
I add the nuget package 
uncomment the #define OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED definition
rebuild and run

and the iphone simulator just stops,
when debugging it seems to never come back from this line.

await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);

I have seen this one
[Azure Mobile app - QuickStart trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344691/azure-mobile-app-quickstart-trouble)

my xamarin app has

```
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
```

any help appreciated, 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the Xamarion.Forms version 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data

(deleted the windows and andriod projects and it works.)

the difference in the TodoService.cs Xamarin.Forms calls SyncContext without the await.

```
this.client.SyncContext.InitalizeAsync(store);
```

were as the Xamarin.IOS QSTodoService.cs has await SyncContext

```
await client.SyncContext.InitalizeAsync(store);
```

ok onto next step.  Hope this helps someone else.